# Having major issues with xpath against soap, Please

Tags: xml, xpath, xmldom

I am having major difficulty getting the value of certain nodes in this soap message. Please help.

I need to get SubTotal node (value=68682):

**"/child::soap:Envelope/child::soap:Body/child::def:ValuationOut/child::def:MMHValuation/child::def:CalculationResult/child::def:PrimaryStructureStandardizedCost/child::def:SubTotal"**

For some reason the above xpath expression does not work. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<wsa:Action>http://abcdefg.com/expresslync/rct:ExportValuation-NumResponse</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:81566a22-9b8b-41bc-9e6b-66b72e73773f</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:ad4da6ca-690a-466e-aba0-16e94e153b55</wsa:RelatesTo>
<wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
<wsse:Security>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-a3b7efdc-d0a3-40f9-bb14-8dcc1c64109d">
<wsu:Created>2012-05-16T21:40:53Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2012-05-16T21:45:53Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ValuationOut xmlns="http://abcdefg.com/expresslync/rct">
<MMHValuation xmlns="http://abcdefg.com/expresslync/rct/valuation">
<ValuationIdentifier>
<RecordId>1677849</RecordId>
<PolicyNumber>RBPFIKQNCPVUAELLGVKY</PolicyNumber>
<VersionId>7091601</VersionId>
</ValuationIdentifier>
<RecordType>POL</RecordType>
<PolicyStatus>Complete</PolicyStatus>
<DataSource>BW</DataSource>
<PropertyAddress>
<Address1/>
<Address2/>
<City/>
<StateOrProvince>CA</StateOrProvince>
<ZipOrPostalCode>90048</ZipOrPostalCode>
</PropertyAddress>
<OwnerUser>UnknownUser</OwnerUser>
<AssignedByUser>msbsupport</AssignedByUser>
<CreateDate>2012-05-16T14:40:51.393</CreateDate>
<CreateUser>msbsupport</CreateUser>
<UpdateDate>2012-05-16T14:40:51.393</UpdateDate>
<UpdateStatusDate>2012-05-16T14:40:51.393</UpdateStatusDate>
<UpdateUser>msbsupport</UpdateUser>
<PolicyEffectiveDate>2012-05-16T14:41:00</PolicyEffectiveDate>
<PolicyRenewalDate>2013-05-16T14:41:00</PolicyRenewalDate>
<InsuredCustomer>
<MailingAddressSameAsPropertyAddress>false</MailingAddressSameAsPropertyAddress>
<MailingAddress>
<Address1/>
<Address2/>
<City/>
<StateOrProvince/>
<ZipOrPostalCode/>
</MailingAddress>
</InsuredCustomer>
<CurrentCoverageAmount>111111</CurrentCoverageAmount>
<Comment Type="Some Comment"/>
<Comment Type="Some Other Comment"/>
<AttachmentCount>0</AttachmentCount>
<CalculationResult>
<CalcUser>somesupport</CalcUser>
<CalcDate>2012-05-16T14:40:51.377</CalcDate>
<CostDataVersion>
<Id>2012/05</Id>
<Description/>
<Date>2012-05-15</Date>
</CostDataVersion>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>0</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>0</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>0</MaterialCost>
<System>Sitework</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>2292</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>11</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>1755</MaterialCost>
<System>Foundations</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>0</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>0</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>0</MaterialCost>
<System>SlabonGrade</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>4043</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>13</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>13964</MaterialCost>
<System>Framing</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>1249</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>0</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>2348</MaterialCost>
<System>Roofing</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>4833</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>85</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>8831</MaterialCost>
<System>ExteriorWalls</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>2619</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>18</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>3040</MaterialCost>
<System>Partitions</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>743</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>9</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>859</MaterialCost>
<System>WallFinishes</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>817</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>0</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>1744</MaterialCost>
<System>FloorFinishes</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>618</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>8</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>329</MaterialCost>
<System>CeilingFinishes</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>1366</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>0</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>2742</MaterialCost>
<System>ElectricalSystems</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>0</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>0</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>0</MaterialCost>
<System>AttachedStructures</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>0</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>0</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>0</MaterialCost>
<System>DetachedStructure</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<BuildingSystemCost>
<LaborCost>0</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>137</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>0</MaterialCost>
<System>GeneralConditions</System>
</BuildingSystemCost>
<PrimaryStructureStandardizedCost>
<InsurableReplacementCost>72109</InsurableReplacementCost>
<InsuredValue>0</InsuredValue>
<Depreciation>0</Depreciation>
<Subtotal>**68682**</Subtotal>
<Adjustment>0</Adjustment>
<ActualCashValue>50477</ActualCashValue>
<LaborCost>21862</LaborCost>
<EquipmentCost>285</EquipmentCost>
<MaterialCost>46535</MaterialCost>
<SubTotal>68682</SubTotal>
<TotalReplacementCost>72109</TotalReplacementCost>
<PolicyExclusions>0</PolicyExclusions>
<HistoricalDepreciation>21632</HistoricalDepreciation>
<RCLessHistoricalDepreciation>50477</RCLessHistoricalDepreciation>
<CurrentCoveragePercentOfIRC>154.00</CurrentCoveragePercentOfIRC>
<DebrisRemoval>3427</DebrisRemoval>
<SubtotalAfterDebrisRemoval>72109</SubtotalAfterDebrisRemoval>
<FinishedFloorArea>1111</FinishedFloorArea>
</PrimaryStructureStandardizedCost>
<DetachedStructuresStandarddizedCost>
<InsurableReplacementCost>0</InsurableReplacementCost>
<InsuredValue>0</InsuredValue>
<Depreciation>0</Depreciation>
<Subtotal>0</Subtotal>
<Adjustment>0</Adjustment>
<ActualCashValue>0</ActualCashValue>
<PercentOfPrimaryStructureIRC>0.00</PercentOfPrimaryStructureIRC>
<DebrisRemoval>0</DebrisRemoval>
<SubtotalAfterDebrisRemoval>0</SubtotalAfterDebrisRemoval>
</DetachedStructuresStandarddizedCost>
<WholeBuildingCost>
<InsurableReplacementCost>72109</InsurableReplacementCost>
<InsuredValue>72109</InsuredValue>
</WholeBuildingCost>
</CalculationResult>
<Preferences>
<ExcavationFlag>true</ExcavationFlag>
</Preferences>
<Adjustment>
<GeneralPercentage>0.00</GeneralPercentage>
<DepreciationChoice>EnteredPercentage</DepreciationChoice>
<DepreciationPercentage>0.00</DepreciationPercentage>
<DepreciationEffectiveAge>0</DepreciationEffectiveAge>
<WageType>Reconstruction</WageType>
<ApplyHistoricalDepreciation>true</ApplyHistoricalDepreciation>
</Adjustment>
<Building>
<SiteAccess>Flat_Area_Roads</SiteAccess>
<HomeStyle>SingleWide</HomeStyle>
<Component>
<Material>015123</Material>
<Amount>100.00</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Material>015001</Material>
<Amount>100.00</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Material>035503</Material>
<Amount>75.00</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Material>055002</Material>
<Amount>1.00</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Material>055102</Material>
<Amount>2.00</Amount>
</Component>
<Component>
<Material>060021</Material>
<Amount>1.00</Amount>
</Component>
<Section>
<Number>1</Number>
<Name>Main</Name>
<YearBuilt>2000</YearBuilt>
<ContructionType>Standard</ContructionType>
<NoOfStories>1.00</NoOfStories>
<LivingArea>1111</LivingArea>
<PerimeterChoice>Shape</PerimeterChoice>
<LivingAreaEntryMethod>TotalLivingArea</LivingAreaEntryMethod>
<FoundationAndBasement>
<PiersRaisedPct>100</PiersRaisedPct>
<BasementPct>0</BasementPct>
</FoundationAndBasement>
<Framing Type="Wood2x4" Percent="100"/>
<HingedRoof>false</HingedRoof>
</Section>
</Building>
</MMHValuation>
</ValuationOut>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: The XPath given is indeed the right way to obtain the element and it works for me. The problem will be somewhere else. As I don't know VB, I can't really help. But try to build up from shorter and easier XPaths, try e.g. `/child::soap:Envelope`. If that can't be found, too, you'll know you have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: Search the internet for: "XPath default namespace" -- also there are many such questions with good answers in the tags "xpath" and "xslt"

Answer (score 0):

just the xpath:
    //SubTotal
wil return you the SubTotal node.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. Here's my vbs script. The //SubTotal did not work.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fw = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\ALOGFILE.txt")

fw.WriteLine("BEFORE CREATE XMLDOM OBJECT")
set xmlDoc=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.async = false
xmlDoc.LoadXml ("C:\TestXml.xml")
fw.WriteLine("AFTER CREATE XMLDOM OBJECT")
Dim SubT, DR, TRC, val1, val2, val3
fw.WriteLine("BEFORE SELECT NODE")

Set Node = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//SubTotal")

fw.WriteLine(Node.text)
fw.WriteLine("AFTER SELECT NODE")

fw.Close


If Not xmlDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End If`

Comment: Try `//Subtotal` or `//valuation:Subtotal`.  XPath is case sensitive.

Comment: The xml file looks a bit messy. Two SubTotal nodes and one Subtotal node (lower case t) appear in the xml structure with similar contents.